Is it possible to access network drives in a process started by CreateProcessWithLogonW?
My goal is to start a child process from a system service for a distinct user which has access to network drives (mapped or UNC).
To simplify the testing scenario, I have created an application for the account which has access to the network drive and I'm creating a child process via CreateProcessWithLogonW with the credentials for this account.
For the login flags I'm using LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, for the creation flags CREATE_NO_WINDOW | NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT and for environment and current directory NULL.
The subordinate process starts, but the FindFirstFileEx fails with code 1326 - ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE which is also the information I see by the Process Monitor from sysinternals.
However, if I steal away the token from the user session by WTSQueryUserToken the CreateProcessAsUser works like a charm and the subsequent process has access to a mapped network drive by FindFirstFileEx. Unfortunately this is not a valid solution, since this is supposed to working without anybody being logged into the system.
I would be grateful for any advice how to solve the problem with CreateProcessWithLogonW or a combination for LogonUser and CreateProcessAsUser.
Thanks in advance,
Achim

you not need create separate process. you need use NetUseAdd if you have user credentials

Thank you for the response, but a separate process as a different user is mandatory in this scenario.

so create this separate process, if you need. and inside it call NetUseAdd

I need to create this process as the distinct user with the right credential to use NetUseAdd. This brings us back to my original request.

for use NetUseAdd you only need have user credentials, which you already have

Exaclty and that are the wrong ones since we are talking about a system service which is not supposed to connect to the network at all.
Bottom line the NetUseAdd does not solve my problem.

if correct call NetUseAdd , with correct parameters, it solve problem

and begin from point - are your user itself have access to this share or user need enter credentials for another user for access it ?

The system does does not have access. Therefor It needs to create a process for the user. IF this user would be initialized with the correct token, he would have access. This is not the case eventhough the network drive is mapped.

Look like you not listening or not understand. I say again and again - you need cal NetUseAdd with correct credentials. Have system access or no unrelated here at all. And you not replying are user have access to share or not. Look like you at all dont understand this point too

Network shares are (re-)connected at login time. Merely running a process as a particular user doesn't magically connect network shares.

Just to clarify this. It is not a matter of mapped profiles. FindFirstFileEx is failing for a UNC path (\server\share\path) with the code 1326 - ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE

@AchimSchön you still complete don't understand situation. and not want listen. you not want reply on key question - are user by self have permission for access share or user need call NetUseAdd with another credentials for use it. if first variant - the code running under your user credentials must be able open file on it. so probably second variant. in this case you anyway need call NetUseAdd or if not want - you must be happy with ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE

Beginning with Windows 2000 SP2, network credentials are tied to a specific logon session authentication ID (a LUID). If you call LogonUser or any API that internally creates a new logon session, this new session will not inherit any mapped drives etc.
In the case of simple UAC elevation, the EnableLinkedConnections registry value can be set to allow all elevated processes to inherit the network credentials of the "original logon session" created on the logon screen (a comment on Superuser claims this registry value no longer works on Windows 10). This workaround does not apply to you if you are a NT service.
If you control the child process you are creating, the child process needs to call NetUseAdd or WNetAddConnection2 to establish network credentials and mapped drives for its logon session. This will require access to the users password. The child process can perhaps ask the service (over a pipe) for the password.
If you don't control the child process, you have to create a process that acts as a middleman that first sets up the network and then calls the regular CreateProcess to create the intended child process.
